# typecast struct pointer into char pointer reference

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, compiler-errors, typecasting-operator

Is it possible to typecast struct pointer into char pointer reference? I know that we can cast any pointer type to any other pointer type. But I got an error when I tried to typecast structure. I am using C++ compiler.

Error :
    error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&' from a temporary of type 'char*'

Please see below example:

```
struct test {
    int a;
    bool y;
    char buf[0];
}

struct test *x_p = NULL;

char *p = "Some random data......";   // this can be more than 64 bytes

x_p = (struct test *) malloc(sizeof(struct test) + 65);
x_p->a = 10;
x_p->y = false;
memcpy(x_p->buf, p, 64); //copy first 64 bytes

/* Here I am getting an error : 
 * error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&' from a temporary of type 'char*'
 */

call_test_fun((char *)x_p);

// Function Declaration 

err_t call_test_fun(char *& data);
```

Comment: The error message would only be produced by a C++ compiler, but you have tagged the question C.  C and C++ are different languages. Please decide which language you want to use; and then use the right compiler for that language and select the corresponding tag, either [c] or [c++] but not both.

Comment: " know that we can cast any pointer type to any other pointer type." --> no, there are restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply @M.M and chux.  Sorry I am using C++ compiler. I will update the question.

Comment: Sorry @chux. I don't know about the restriction. Could you please give me some examples or point me out to some references. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @mehtame026 http://stackoverflow.com/q/17260527/2410359

Comment: I see @chux. I understand that I have to be very careful when doing typecasting.

Comment: @mehtame026 Good code avoids type casting.   Typical there is a _better_ approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function declaration should be:

```
err_t call_test_fun(char * data);
```

you had an erroneous `&` . The function definition should match.

Note that your code uses techniques that are not part of Standard C++:  having a zero-sized array in a struct, and writing directly into malloc'd space.  Maybe you are using a compiler with those things as extensions but it will be frowned on by many people as being prone to error.  There is undoubtedly a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure thanks @M.M. I don't want to remove reference operator since this function gets called at many places.

Comment: @mehtame026 Then you could write: `char *temp = (char *)x_p; call_test_fun(temp);`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!