# how is the size of every pointer variable being 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine justified?

Tags: c, pointers

I went through pointer arithmetic and the fact that you can't assign pointer of one data type to another data type. for example, below declaration is incorrect.

```
  double x = 10;
  int *ptrInt = &x;
```

We've assigned the address of double variable to a "pointer to integer". Double takes 8 bytes as compared to an integer, that takes 4 bytes and therefore an integer pointer will truncate those extra 4 bytes.

But how come, the size of any pointer variable is 8 bytes and that also means it will not truncate those extra 4 bytes and should work correctly(even though it doesn't).

I have this doubt. Can anybody help me with the clarification?

Comment: The pointer is the address. The variable (x) is what lives at that address. If you assign the address of a double to an int pointer and dereference the int pointer, you're going to get sizeof(int) bytes out. It's a strange workflow, so you have to jump through some hoops to say "yes, I really want to do this". And you probably don't

Comment: The size of a pointer has nothing to do with the size of the object it points to.  A 64-bit pointer supports a 64-bit address space.  For instance, suppose you had an array of 2**34 character variables.  You would need a minimum of 34 address bits to address every element of the array, even though the elements themselves are only 1 byte each.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260931/2850543

Comment: Think about `printf ("pointer size: %lu-bytes\n", sizeof (void*));`

Answer (score 5):

*how come, the size of any pointer variable is 8 bytes ?* pointer variable contains address & size of address is `8 byte` on `64-bit` system irrespective of whether pointer variable points to `int` or `char` or `float` objects as `64-bit` pointer supports `8 byte` address space.

Comment: OK, but if the pointer only supports `8-byte` address space, why do tools like `objdump -x` report address with 16 bytes?